# About sub control's response after SetCapture() in parent window

Tags: mfc, window, controls

I create a window in a view and create a scrollbar control in that window.

The window has edit mode. In edit mode, it will call SetCapture() and all the mouse event messages are sent to the window. So the other windows in that view will be disabled and have no chance for mouse operation in edit mode.

But it causes the following problem:
- In edit mode, mouse operation in Scrollbar makes no response. Because of SetCapture() to parent window.

So how can I SetCapture() a window but make the sub control respond to mouse operation?

Answer (score -1):

`SetCapture` must not be called outside `WM_*BUTTONDOWN`. Read the documentation!

Comment: From my understanding this answer does not match the MSDN documentation as described here https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646262(v=vs.85).aspx. 
It sounds like what is done in the example here (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms645602(v=vs.85).aspx#drawing_lines) but it is not a constraint of using the function.

Comment: The purpose of the `SetCapture` API is to capture mouse events from a certain window, no matter if the mouse is above the window or not. Constraint or not, if called in a non-`WM_*BUTTONDOWN` handler, the mouse messages will not be captured. MSDN loses. I win.

Comment: I believe that I have observed different behaviour.

Comment: I verified this in an `MFC` dialog project. If you can produce different behavior, it would be interesting to see how. Preferably on `Windows 7` or later.

Comment: In a custom window (non MFC on windows 8) SetCapture called outside of any event handler, all messages captured by the window (observed in Spy++ and in the code).  However this design was then abandoned for reasons similar to described in this question - messages were not forwarded to child windows if not handled by the capturing window.  I agree that the button down case is the common case and it may not be a good idea to try and use SetCapture to achieve other things.